# Why is this 301 Redirecting?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a WordPress site that I'm trying to speed up with the help of GTMetrix. I noticed whenever I test a page and omit the trailing slash to the URL (e.g. `http://example.com/blog`), it does a 301 redirect to that URL with the trailing slash appended (e.g. `http://example.com/blog/`).

The redirect is taking about 1 second and I would like to shave that time off, if possible. Questions:

1. What's causing this redirect? Is it a configuration in WP, .htaccess, or something else?
2. What can I do to prevent this redirect and not break my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That redirect is done by Apache using `mod_dir`. It does this by default to directories using the `DirectorySlash` directive. If you wish for it not to do that you can turn it off using this in .htaccess.

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

But becareful as this can have side affects (such as `DirectoryIndex` not working) which you can see about here.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash